# Mapping country name to multiple-region designation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe containing a **'COUNTRY'** column. I want to insert into the dataframe a new column, **'REGION'**, that includes in each row a list of regions that the country belongs to. For example, if the **'COUNTRY'** column is:

```
In [5]: df['COUNTRY']
Out[5]: 
0            ITALY
1    UNITED STATES
2            CHINA
3           FRANCE
4           BRAZIL
Name: COUNTRY, dtype: object
```

I want the **'REGION'** column to be:

```
df['REGION']
Out[8]: 
0          [ROW, EU]
1    [UNITED STATES]
2        [ROW, ASIA]
3          [ROW, EU]
4          [ROW]
Name: REGION, dtype: object
```

**'ROW'** stands for rest-of-the-world, **'EU'** for Europe, etc.

I tried the following with `np.select()`, but I am getting an error.

```
    # insert region column
    condlist = [
        (df.COUNTRY == 'ITALY'),
        (df.COUNTRY == 'UNITED STATES'),
        (df.COUNTRY != 'UNITED STATES'),
        (df.COUNTRY == 'CHINA'),
    ]
    region = [
        ['ROW', 'EU'],
        ['UNITED STATES'],
        ['ROW'],
        ['ROW', 'ASIA']
    ]
    print(np.select(condlist, region, ['ROW']))
```

Note that for a country that is not included in the `condlist[]` tests, I want to assign it the region `['ROW']`.

The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way I believe. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the different sized lists into the Dataframe so you'd just have to do a query on the contents of Region to determine if "ROW" and "EU" are present.

```
countries = ['ITALY', 'UNITED STATES', 'CHINA', 'FRANCE', 'BRAZIL']

regions = [['ROW, EU'], ['UNITED STATES'], ['ROW, ASIA'], ['ROW, EU'], ['ROW']]

region_map = dict(zip(countries, regions))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'COUNTRY': countries})

df['REGION'] = ""

for country in region_map:
    df.loc[df['COUNTRY'] == country, 'REGION'] = region_map[country]

print(df)

         COUNTRY         REGION
0          ITALY        ROW, EU
1  UNITED STATES  UNITED STATES
2          CHINA      ROW, ASIA
3         FRANCE        ROW, EU
4         BRAZIL            ROW
```

Answer (score 0):

What I like about the solution by @nanobennett is the use of a string for the regions instead of a list. Using a string for the region makes it easier to insert the region into a dataframe column and manipulate using the .str accessors. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
   regions = countries.copy()
   for country in countries.unique():

           region = ''

           # ROW
           if country != 'UNITED STATES':
               region += 'ROW, '

           # all other countries
           if country in alant.local.EU:
               region += 'EU, '
               if country in alant.local.DACH:
                   region += 'DACH, '
               elif country in alant.local.NORDIC:
                   region += 'NORDIC, '
               elif country in alant.local.BENELUX:
                   region += 'BENELUX, '
           elif country in alant.local.SA:
               region += 'SA, '
           elif country in ['CANADA', 'UNITED STATES']:
               region += 'NA, '
               if country == 'UNITED STATES':
                   region += 'US, '

           # special country blocs
           if country in alant.local.BRICS:
               region += 'BRICS, '

           regions[countries == country] = region.rstrip(' ,')

   return regions
```

where for the lists used in the `if elif` tests:
alant.local.EU is a list of the European countries, alant.local.DACH are a list of the DACH countries, i.e., ['AUSTRIA', 'GERMANY', 'SWITZERLAND'], etc.

I believe this solution can be improved, perhaps using the 3.10 switch statement, and the `pycountry` or other packages I am not aware of. but for now it does the job for me.